# Strange artefacts with imagecreatefrompng and imagepng compression

Tags: php, image, png, gd

My simple goal was to compress PNG files with the following code:

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng("test.png");
imagepng($image, "result.png", 9, PNG_ALL_FILTERS);
```

I've also tried with zero and default compression, with the same results.

Original file is like this:

[image: source image]

But the result on some (not all) images was like this:

[image: broken result]

The only way, I can produce good results is with this additional code:

```
imagealphablending($image, false);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
```

Why does this simple image manipulation produce this kind of artefacts? And by saving full alpha information, do I get into troubles with some browsers or unneeded filesize?

Is there any other foolproof solution, which would losslessly compress png files?

Comment: Maybe because you have set "9" as compression level which means the maximum compression, try to set 0 or 1 ?

Comment: @weeger: I've also tried 0  and without, so that can't be the problem

Comment: @zeldi, You're using this in the correct manner. The reason for the strange transparency is that without `imagesavealpha` on 24-bit images the opaque pixels are resampled in single transparency mode.

Comment: @I'L'I: doesn't this info get read and set from source PNG file? Do I have to set it manually?